# Simple method for checking value of listbox not working Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am probably missing something really stupid here, but I have a button and a listbox (with only 1 column) on a userform.

Whenever the button is pressed, it's going to check if the value from the listbox is empty. If it is empty, a msgbox "Nothing selected" will pop up. If it isn't empty, a msgbox with the value will pop-up. If there is no value, it still goes to the "not empty" section and then gives the error

> Run-time error '94':
>
> Invalid use of Null

And that's my problem.

My simple code is:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    If Not IsEmpty(ListBox.Value) Then
        'Something is selected in the listbox
        MsgBox (ListBox.Value)
    Else
        'Nothing is selected in the listbox
        MsgBox ("Nothing selected")
    End If
End Sub
```

Am I really doing something wrong here? I don't see what.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing `IsEmpty(ListBox.Value)` to `ListBox.Value = ""`. I thought that the `IsEmpty()`-method also worked, but apparently not.

Full working code:

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    If Not playersMainSetup.Value = "" Then
        'Something is selected in the listbox
        MsgBox ListBox.Value
    Else
        'Nothing is selected in the listbox
         MsgBox "Nothing selected"
    End If
End Sub
```